# mysqlsh JSON document store find documents using wildcard filed name

Tags: mysql-8.0, mysql

I have JSON documents in the below format,

**doc1**

```
"static_field1": {
    "dynamic_field1": {
        "static_field11": {
            "static_field111": "value1",
            "static_field112": "value2",
            "static_field113": "value3",
            "static_field114": "value4",
            "static_field115": {
                "dynamic_field111": "value5"
            },
            "static_field116": "value6"
        },
        "static_field12": {
            "dynamic_field111": [
                "value7"
            ]
        },
        "static_field13": {
            "dynamic_field1111": {}
        }
    }
}
```

**doc2**

```
"static_field2": {
    "dynamic_field2": {
        "static_field21": {
            "static_field111": "value11",
            "static_field112": "value21",
            "static_field113": "value31",
            "static_field114": "value41",
            "static_field115": {
                "dynamic_field211": "value51"
            },
            "static_field116": "value61"
        },
        "static_field12": {
            "dynamic_field211": [
                "value71"
            ]
        },
        "static_field13": {
            "dynamic_field2111": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I have added these documents on the MySQL JSON document store using `db.testdata.add(<json_doc>)`. In my JSON document the filed `dynamic_field1` and `dynamic_field2` are dynamic fields and it will be dynamic for each documents which I will insert. After adding those documents I would like to get the documents with the filter `static_field1.*.static_field11.static_field114="value4"`. As far my understanding using `*` as wildcard in the field won't as it will be like `select col* from table`. So is there any way to overcome this to find the documents using the wildcard in the field? Or is there any other better approach to over this situation for this kind of dynamic JSON documents? I tried `Elasticsearch` which works somewhat but it crashes when I use such kind of wildcard query with multiple wildcard fields.

Comment: Check Json searching functions in MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html Your problem statement is unclear, and without looking at sample data and expected output; it is hard to figure out what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Let me take look. All I want is to find the documents where the filter `"static_field114": "value4"` matches.